# Load testing of AWS Redshift

Tags: performance, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am new to AWS Redshift. Although i have read the concepts, I wanted to know how to proceed with the Load testing in RedShift. I have been very comfortable with the GRINDER, but rather confused how to use with RedShift.
my basic requirement is to push certain number of rows and measure the query and server performance. I have been doing much performance review on cloud where MySQL, Cassandra etc has been deployeed.Please help me with some concept or tool to start with the Load testing.

Comment: Amazon Redshift is a DWH for analytics. Load testing has difference meaning than RDBMS where you need to be able to process many transaction fast.
For example, with Redshift you should COPY data in and not INSERT. It will give the power of parallel processing of MPP of Redshift.

Answer (score 0):

Grinder is inappropriate for Redshift as it is designed to test the impact of multiple concurrent users reading and writing data. [Redshift performs poorly for single row inserts as per the docs.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_INSERT_30.html)

For Redshift you should be evaluating the performance at certain data sizes and query complexity. Look into the Star Schema Benchmark or TPC-H.